# Adding transportation schedules to a network dataset

Tags: arcgis-10.0, network-analyst, database-model, multimodal-network

How do I add transportation schedules to a multimodal network dataset? For example, Bus 1 runs between 08:00 and 16:00, and Bus 2 between 14:00 and 23:00. If a passenger wants to solve for a route starting at 16:30, Bus 1 cannot be included in the result as it is not in service at that time.

After some research, I came across [this article](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCYQFjAA&url=http://www.sajim.co.za/index.php/SAJIM/article/download/386/373&ei=fHONUNSQI8-GhQeMzYCQDg&usg=AFQjCNGce-uEMCFO5pYfrM80fmqxZK2ZBQ) about managing a public transit system in GIS using ArcInfo 8 (the article is from 2004). The transit data model is essentially the same as the one that ESRI currently has available, except they added a table called `ScheduleTimetable`, which contains the bus schedules which are related to routes. This table can't be added to the network dataset though, as file gdb tables can't be stored inside a feature dataset (and therefore can't be used in a network dataset). How would I be able to access the time fields so they can be used as restrictions for the routes?

Comment: ArcLogistics - http://www.esri.com/software/arclogistics-10/features - demo http://www.esri.com/software/arclogistics-10/browser

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I'm not sure if that's exactly what I need. What is the purpose then of setting a `Start Time` in the `Analysis` Settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post on timetable-based routing](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/59635-Timetable-based-routing?p=221945&viewfull=1#post221945) on the ArcGIS forums, this is not possible as of yet in Network Analyst.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom Evaluator kind this one: http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=72ef24542857413c8981f2e196f1bb13

I have personalized this importaing transit data in network dataset creating on the fly:

```
 
//distance evaluator
            IEvaluatedNetworkAttribute evaluatedNetworkAttribute = new EvaluatedNetworkAttributeClass();
            INetworkAttribute2 networkAttribute = (INetworkAttribute2)evaluatedNetworkAttribute;
            networkAttribute.Name = "Minutes";
            networkAttribute.UsageType = esriNetworkAttributeUsageType.esriNAUTCost;
            networkAttribute.DataType = esriNetworkAttributeDataType.esriNADTDouble;
            networkAttribute.Units = esriNetworkAttributeUnits.esriNAUMinutes;
            networkAttribute.UseByDefault = true;
```

INetworkConstantEvaluator netConstantEvaluator = new NetworkConstantEvaluatorClass();
        netConstantEvaluator.ConstantValue = 0;
        evaluatedNetworkAttribute.set_Evaluator(networkSourceEdge, esriNetworkEdgeDirection.esriNEDAlongDigitized, (INetworkEvaluator)netConstantEvaluator);
        evaluatedNetworkAttribute.set_Evaluator(networkSourceEdge, esriNetworkEdgeDirection.esriNEDAgainstDigitized, (INetworkEvaluator)netConstantEvaluator);

        DepartureTimeEvaluator.DepartureTimeEvaluator departureTimeEvaluator = new DepartureTimeEvaluator.DepartureTimeEvaluator();

        IPropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet();


        propertySet.SetProperty(DepartureTimeEvaluator.DepartureTimeEvaluator.PROPNAME_SCHEDULE_PATHGDB, featureDataset.Workspace.PathName);
        propertySet.SetProperty(DepartureTimeEvaluator.DepartureTimeEvaluator.PROPNAME_SCHEDULE_TABLE, DepartureTimeEvaluator.DepartureTimeEvaluator.DEFAULT_TABLE);
        propertySet.SetProperty(DepartureTimeEvaluator.DepartureTimeEvaluator.PROPNAME_SOURCEID_FIELDNAME, DepartureTimeEvaluator.DepartureTimeEvaluator.DEFAULT_SOURCEID_FIELDNAME);
        propertySet.SetProperty(DepartureTimeEvaluator.DepartureTimeEvaluator.PROPNAME_OID_FIELDNAME, DepartureTimeEvaluator.DepartureTimeEvaluator.DEFAULT_OID_FIELDNAME);
        propertySet.SetProperty(DepartureTimeEvaluator.DepartureTimeEvaluator.PROPNAME_DEPARTURETIMES_FIELDNAME, DepartureTimeEvaluator.DepartureTimeEvaluator.DEFAULT_DEPARTURETIMES_FIELDNAME);
        departureTimeEvaluator.Data = propertySet;

        evaluatedNetworkAttribute.set_Evaluator(networkSourceJunction, esriNetworkEdgeDirection.esriNEDNone, departureTimeEvaluator);


        evaluatedNetworkAttribute.set_DefaultEvaluator(esriNetworkElementType.esriNETEdge, (INetworkEvaluator)netConstantEvaluator);
        evaluatedNetworkAttribute.set_DefaultEvaluator(esriNetworkElementType.esriNETJunction, (INetworkEvaluator)netConstantEvaluator);

        IArray attributeArray = new ArrayClass();
        attributeArray.Add(evaluatedNetworkAttribute);
        deNetworkDataset.Attributes = attributeArray;

Answer (score 0):

I have recently visited the link that you shared originally - it seems that the discussion continued and now it is possible to incorporate Add GTFS to a Network Dataset - http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=0fa52a75d9ba4abcad6b88bb6285fae1 - I am currently attempting to incorporate time tables into a multimodal public transport network myself. So perhaps this could assist.

Comment: Hey Winston, nice to see you here :) Yes, at the time that option did not exist. I got in contact with Melinda Morang at ESRI, who was developing that tool. By the time it came out, the project I needed it for had already been completed. This definitely seemed like a viable option. If you use this, please post back here?